# Moving the camera in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a camera, and i need that when i click on screen, camera slowly and smoothly(or not) move to a specified position. So how to make camera move?

Comment: Why is this not a real question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `SmoothCamera`.

Create your camera this way:

```
SmoothCamera camera = new SmoothCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

Limit the maximum velocity for the camera to move:

```
camera.setMaxVelocity(MAX_VELOCITY_X, MAX_VELOCITY_Y);
```

And in the `onSceneTouchEvent` method do:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pTouchEvent) {
    (SmoothCamera object here).setCenter(pTouchEvent.getX(), pTouchEvent.getY());
}
```